# Calling a React class in a pure js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pure javascript file from which Im getting all the inputs, it's a legacy code. Now I want a react component to get called from the javascript file

`App(exercise, event);`    //Something like this, App is my React class. exercise and event are inputs from js file

So in my case as the inputs are getting stored in the js file from various dropdowns, the js file is the entry point of my application.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(<div>
      {console.log(this.props)}
    </div>)
  }
}
```

How should my React class be imported in js file so it can be called and I can see the exercise and event in props of react

Currently Im getting `Uncaught Reference Error: App is not defined` in the console output

Comment: The big problem you are facing is that React uses a Virtual Dom while pure js does not. I believe you will need to refactor your old js code into react components.

Comment: Is there a way I can just have the inputs to get transferred there, Rest code is working fine just that I need the inputs from here. Exercise and Event values from the js to React somehow ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with JQuery. Mixture React and JQuery code could be difficult and hard to maintain. This might help you: http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/

Answer (score 0):

Your js code can mount the component and pass in the initial properties to it.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {...properties}), document.getElementById('target'))
```

Comment: It's still saying `Uncaught Reference Error: App is not defined`. How do I give the import in this js file ?

Comment: That depends on your application tooling.  If you are not already using something like webpack or babelify you could try using the native browser module support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html